# Смена изображения при наведении курсора

Tags: javascript

Я хочу научиться делать следующее: вот у меня есть картинка `image1` и, если на неё навели курсор, то она меняется на `image2`. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что лучше css псевдокласс `hover`. http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/content/img-hover.html

А можно на Jquery

```js
$('img.class').hover(
    function { $('img.destination').attr('src', 'адрес картинки'); }, //<тут меняем картинку
    function { $('img.destination').attr('src', 'адрес картинки'); } //<тут меняем картинку обратно(то есть когда курсор мыши уходит за пределы img.class)
);
```

Comment: бред у вас! прочитай про псевдоклассы!!!!

Comment: Вы действительно думаете что я незнаю что такое пседоклассы?<br><br>
Тем не менее - прошу прощения, я думал вы написали этот комментарий к js коду, вот и возмутился ^^

Comment: Плюсы использования этого метода?
IMHO Эффект тот же что и обычный :hover css-овский .
<a href="http://htmlbook.ru">Черпайте отсюда</a>

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/1tvefvv3/

```css
img{
    max-width: 100%;    
}
.wrapper-img{    
    position: relative;
    max-width: 300px;
}
.wrapper-img .img-hide{    
    opacity: 0;      
}
.wrapper-img:hover .img-hide{
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;  
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-img">
    <img src="http://cs304807.vk.me/v304807597/365a/TPcDNnItHrw.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="img-hide" src="http://cs416726.vk.me/v416726759/3384/dU3iWhgVsus.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос древний, автор не заходил с 11-го года, это не JS, как просил автор.
Зачем тогда ответил?

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд лучше использовать чистый CSS или технологию rollover: [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/invincible/6wmcf/)

П.С. обновил ссылку, фидл как всегда глючит

Comment: Любопытно - покажите мне пожалуйста эти волшебные строки которые поменяют <b>src</b> изображения?

Comment: Дивы не лишние, там всего два дива.
В первом используется ролловер эффект, когда картинка больше, чем див. А показываем мы только нужную часть картинки, в зависимости от состояния.

А во втором случае, полностью меняется и картинка и размер дива.

Answer (score 0):

Присоединяюсь что-бы сделать все на CSS

Все зависит от того в каком это будет контексте, так например для меню или чего-то подобного то: http://jsfiddle.net/szVm4/1/ - из улучшений - можно собрать картинки в спрайт и менять их с помощью background-position

Если действия при нажатии не происходит, то можно сделать примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/szVm4/2/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="image"></div>

<style type="text/css">
.image {
background-image:url(path/to/image);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.image:hover {
тут все тоже самое только для 2-ой картинки
}
</style>
```

Вроде так )

Answer (score 0):

Более простой вариант:

```html
<a href="#"
   onMouseOver="document.getElementByid('test').src='test_2.png'"
   onMouseOut="document.getElementByid('test').src='test_1.png'">
   <img id="test" href="test_1.png" align="left"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

если это картинка (img) то это нужно делать на JS

onmove - this.src="image2.jpg"

onblur - this.src="image1.jpg"

Comment: А примеч тут onblur? O_o<br>
Какой ужас ^^<br>
Может всетаки <b>onmouseover</b> И <b>onmouseout</b>, не?